# R: divide variable in dataframe by specific value from list or vector

Tags: r

I'm a newb at R, so forgive my ignorance.

I have a dataframe that consists of two variables: Location and response. I have another dataframe that consists of sampling effort at each location. I need to divide the response by the sampling effort using the location as the identifier. I know there is probably an easy solution, but I'm striking out finding it. I would appreciate any help.

```
Example:
Dataframe 1

Location Response

Loc1     25

Loc2     63

Loc3     5.63


Dataframe2

Location Sampling effort

Loc1     2

Loc2     6.5

Loc3     3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `dplyr`/`tidyverse` approach:

#### code to replicate your dataframes

```
df1 <- 
    read.table(text = "Location Response
                        Loc1     25
                        Loc2     63
                        Loc3     5.63
                      ", header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
df2 <- 
    read.table(text = "Location  Sampling_effort
                        Loc1     2
                        Loc2     6.5
                        Loc3     3
                      ", header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

#### code to generate the effect size calculation

```
library(dplyr)
df_joined <- 
    df1 %>% 
    left_join(df2) %>% 
    mutate(Effect_size = Response / Sampling_effort)
```

which results in:

> ```
> > df_joined
>   Location Response Sampling_effort Effect_size
> 1     Loc1    25.00             2.0   12.500000
> 2     Loc2    63.00             6.5    9.692308
> 3     Loc3     5.63             3.0    1.876667
> ```

There are lots of good introductions to manipulating data in R, but we did find the datacamp one to be useful - though it is not free anymore.

Answer (score 4):

You can merge them using `merge()` and then just divide two columns:

```
df3 <- merge(df1, df2)
df3$solution <- df3$Response / df3$Sampling_effort
df3
 # Location Response Sampling_effort  solution
 # 1   Loc1    25.00          2.0    12.500000
 # 2   Loc2    63.00          6.5     9.692308
 # 3   Loc3     5.63          3.0     1.876667
```

---

I used the data:

```
df1 <- structure(list(Location = structure(1:3, .Label = c("Loc1", "Loc2", 
         "Loc3"), class = "factor"), Response = c(25, 63, 5.63)), .Names = c("Location", 
         "Response"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L))

df2 <- structure(list(Location = structure(1:3, .Label = c("Loc1", "Loc2", 
           "Loc3"), class = "factor"), Sampling_effort = c(2, 6.5, 3)), .Names = c("Location", 
           "Sampling_effort"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
df1$Response/df2$Sampling_effort[match(df1$Location, df2$Location)]
#[1] 12.500000  9.692308  1.876667
```

Answer (score 0):

As your dataframes follow the same order, it should be sufficient to do

```
df1[,2]/df2[,2]
```